Adding days in current date in DialogFlow cx
I want to add days in current date for using that as an expiry date.
$sys.func.ADD_DATE($sys.func.NOW(), 4, 'DAYS')
I am using this function but it doesn't generating any response, I also  don't want to use webhook.
Please help and also suggest other possibilites to do that in dialogflow.

It worked but small changes required,
